# How to to store variables at specific offset

Tags: c++, variables, offset, portable-executable

Is there a way to store variable (in C++) at specific offset in PE file?
Similar question: Can I define specific order of variables stored in data section?

I've heard there are programs which can store settings in their executables.

Comment: This sounds as if you think being able to store them at such an offset is solving a certain problem. It might be more useful when you ask about that real problem, or at least tell what it is, so people might have a wider set of options to chose from.

Comment: I don't actually need to implement it. But some time ago I was trying to save settings in my executable and couldn't find a way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size of data, you could use deprecated (unused) areas of a PE image (like the MS-DOS Stub) to store your variables. The offsets of many of these unused areas are well-known (since they are defined by the PE format).

Comment: Please keep in mind that, DLLs can be relocated. EXEs are actually never relocated (since they always start first, and thus never conflict with other PE images in memory).

Answer (score 1):

The "easiest" way is to use the resource section. You don't need an offset: `LoadString` takes an ID instead, which is stable over rebuilds. However, as the name suggests, that's only the Load part. Windows locks your executable while executing, which makes the `SaveString` part a *lot* harder.

Not that the lock doesn't really matter, because your program probably is stored in `\Program Files\` and users can't write there anyway.

Comment: Thanks but I'm actually more interested in pure offset solution :).